# Correct way to do node long polling

Tags: javascript, node.js, long-polling

Seems there's a lot of discussion about how to do this but I haven't found any concrete examples. My node application is accessing a RESTful API that is just going to pass through to a database. my initial solution is this

```
function getRecord() {
    var req = https.request(options, function(res){
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            var record = JSON.parse(data.toString('utf-8'));
            //do some database things then do it all over
            getRecord();
        });
    });
    req.write(queryString);
    req.end();
}
```

This accomplishes what I want. I'm going to keep getting new records from the API, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach to doing what I want.

Comment: Do you control the REST API? And if not, does the API contain any "register callbacks" methods that you can hook into? So, if the data changes behind the API, that the API initiates a call to your registered callback.

Comment: I wish this was the case but unfortunately, no. Right now the company providing these apis have nothing in their road map about making it streaming or providing callbacks for when new data is posted.

Answer (score 1):

One (especially favorable) alternative is to switch to a bus architecture with a message server such as RabbitMQ.

You would need to either control the API or have an API that you can register callbacks with.

Long polling is a strategy that can degrade performance and bloat logs quite quickly. Event driven methods, like I've listed above, are much preferred if its a possibility. And, unlike long polling, event driven strategies don't introduce any latency. So if latency is a concern, the more frequent you poll, the more it will degrade performance and bloat logs.

Comment: I will definitely look into a message queue as a solution. Can I ask why RabbitMQ jumped to the front of your mind as a suggestion?

Comment: actually sorry misread your answer as that I wouldn't have to control the api. I'll still look at them though in case they do decide to supply us with streaming or callbacks.

Comment: That's too bad about not having control over the APIs or having callbacks. If you're new to message servers, I really liked this book when getting into them: http://www.manning.com/videla/ It explains the ideology, pros and cons better that I can do here. However, to solve your problem, there are plenty of other rabbit clients (including CLI - see http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html). So, you could program a simple croned CLI, Python or PHP script that only pushed a message into an exchange when it finds a new result. I recommend Python's pika package, if you're familiar with python.

Comment: The advantage of that is that if other services want to take advantage of that API data, they don't have to have a dependency on your node package or the API. They just listen for messages and they're in the loop. If you need to poll more frequently than once a minute, I created a very stable frequent-cron package. I use it in a number of production environments. The useful part about it is that it blocks, so you don't have to worry about overlapping calls. See https://github.com/homer6/frequent-cron

Comment: Thank you for all the information. Even if we're stuck with polling for the time being, the message queue sounds like a great thing to have because it takes away the dependency on the node app like you said.